# Was there ever a LEGO store in Miami International Airport?

Tags: lego-store

I was lately in Miami International Airport (MIA), and there are many signs displaying their array of stores within the airport. One wall I saw was showing logos of the stores in a design way, not in a directory format. It had the news stands, M&M logo, and then I saw the LEGO logo. I have been searching it up, but I can't seem to find any recognition of a LEGO store being or once being in the airport. There had to be some sort of planning for that small, but pervasive logo to be in the airport. Note: I found a (bad) picture of where the logo is. I circled the logo to show you one place it is found. I only have found it on wall displays that look as such. [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't find any mention of a full LEGO store in MIA on the web.  Looking at the other logos that are recognizable I would guess that they don't represent full stores, but products available in the existing stores.  I doubt Jack Daniels and Johnny Walker have free-standing stores in the airport.  I don't see any sign that Jack Daniels has any free-standing stores.

There is a [Mindworks Toys](https://www.yelp.com/biz/mindworks-toys-miami) in MIA which probably sells LEGO sets.  I'd guess that's the source of the logo for this sign.